# Can we use nosql databases as Hive metastore?

Tags: hadoop, hive

I understand that Hadoop community promotes using RDBMS using as hive metastore. But can we use nosql databases like mongodb or hbase  for hive metastore?
If not then why? What is the criteria to choose a database for hive metastore?

Comment: There is an outstanding JIRA for using Hbase as a metastore https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-9452

Comment: Thanks @cricket_007

Answer (score -1):

If you are using the Cloudera Distribution,

Cloudera strongly encourages you to use MySQL because it is the most popular with the rest of the Hive user community, and, hence, receives more testing than the other options.

It stores metadata for Hive tables (like their schema and location) and partitions in a relational database. So we can only use the Relational DB.

If you want the NoSQl, we can go with the MariaDB for the Metastore. as Maria DB is a No SQL Kind Relational DB.

Comment: MariaDB is just an open source fork of MySQL

Comment: mariadb is another RDBMS, as mentioned by @cricket_007 , it is forked from MySql.

Comment: Yes right –@ cricket_007 , MariaDB also include GIS and JSON features in latest version.

Comment: Just because it supports nested (geo)JSON fields doesn't automatically make it noSQL